# Internet Explorer flickering issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, dom

I'm building a web app that includes a running animation that reproduces the behavior of a non-portable `marquee` element. I'm using http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/ for that effect but the root cause of the problem does not seem directly related to the library itself (it's just the trigger that exposes the problem).

The exact issue is as follows:

I have an html `form` with several `input` text fields which the user must fill. The `marquee` animation is running every X milliseconds (where X is lower than 1 second). Whenever a text field is focused (the user clicks on it with the intent of filling it out), the text cursor does not blink (as it should) and stays permanently in bar form (as a `|` sign - pardon my language... :-) ).

I have stripped down the offending code to the bare minimum and you can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyVqk/.

To test, just press the `Start` button and then click on text field. A dot should be appended to the label below the input text every time the animation runs and the cursor should not blink (that's the problem). Please note that if the animation runs in time intervals greater than 1 second, this does not happen (you can test this in the previous fiddle) and the cursor blinks as expected. This has led me to believe the problem lies in the way the browser performs the rendering of the text and unfocus/refocus the field during the update process.

This issue is specific to Internet Explorer (at least in version 6), as other major browsers (Firefox and Chrome) do not present this behavior. I've tried updating the label through the DOM's object `innerHTML` directly but with no success. The exact content that's changed is of no importance either. If the animation only reads properties from the element, the issue does not present itself (only when updating the element's properties - any property).

Since the project I'm working on has high visibility and client exposure, the client is not willing to let that pass. Can anybody shed some light on why this happens? Is there a workaround (attaching/detaching elements from the DOM before/after animation, refocusing after animation, etc.)? Please note that losing the `marquee` effect is not an option.

Comment: IE6 is almost dead, don't worry about this little visual glitch. IE6's javascript support is HORRIBLE, and that's where the problem is coming from.

Comment: As I said, can't do that, since the client relies on it (believe me, I would love to let IE die a painful death, if I could ;-)). Even then, the issue is not only specific to IE6. It also happens for IE7 (just confirmed it in IETester).

Comment: Could you just use the actual `marquee` tag in IE using conditional comments?

Comment: @cdeszaq "IE6 is almost dead", false (at least for me). 12% of my users (people browsing my sites) still use it.

Comment: @Guandalino - Microsoft just announced they will be forcing all IE6 users to upgrade, so I imagine that won't be a problem much longer. http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/microsoft-to-start-silent-upgrades-to-internet-explorer/

Comment: @MystereMan - That is not entirely true, since Microsoft is offering an "alternative" upgrade path to customers that do not rely on automatic Windows updates (as is the case of most large companies). Our project's browser requirements are not going away any time soon...

Comment: They aren't actually "forcing" users to upgrade, If windows update isn't turned on it can't automatically update Internet Explorer. More than likely the same people who don't know how to update Internet Explorer or refuse to are the same people who don't have windows update turned on. But all that doesn't matter because this issue happens in IE7 and 8 too, both of which will be around for a long time.

Comment: @cdeszaq The "IE conditional comments" is not a bad idea as a workaround, but the project is much larger and I'd like to guarantee this does not happen again due to some other event. I'll keep your idea in mind, though.

Comment: @cdeszaq I just tested your idea and it doesn't work either. <code>marquee</code> also stops the cursor from blinking. Since this is native browser functionality, I would say there's really nothing that can be done. Can it be that IE removes the element's focus during its internal rendering loop and then reattaches it at the previous location? Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Under the covers, it could be doing all sorts of things. Since even the native tag breaks things, I would suggest that a different UI be used for IE browsers. Rather than a scrolling Marquee, perhaps a "rotating" element instead that rotates through pieces of a message, rather than scrolling them all through. Similar function, slightly different presentation. That's the essence of the web, really, and if the client doesn't like it, tell them that's just how the web is, and they should complain to Microsoft, not you.

Comment: @MystereMan yes, finally Microsoft will bring auto-update to IE. Thanks God. But starting from Australia and Brazil. [They don't say](http://windowsteamblog.com/ie/b/ie/archive/2011/12/15/ie-to-start-automatic-upgrades-across-windows-xp-windows-vista-and-windows-7.aspx) *when* this will happen for other countries. Even worse, users can opt-out. The bottom line for me is we have to support this old browser for a long time yet...

Comment: Even disabling jQuery and trying to accomplish the same result with getElementById and innerHTML does not solve the problem. I tried removing the <p> from the <div>, adding <br> before it, and even entering other dom objects between the input field and paragraph... But when I disable the $p.text($p.text() + '.'); line everything seems fine. So it must be a rendering/redrawing issue. Is it possible that IE6 is redrawing the text caret ( | character ) on every timer call?

Answer (score 0):

I got some flickering probs with IE in the past, don't know if it is the same as yours, but give it a try :

```
//@cc_on document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);// don't remove : prevent IE6 cursor blinking
```

Then another fix I remember is to set a fixed background to the body...